# caption in subfigures with different textwidths

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I want to put one picture in a row three times with different textwidths. The following code does the job but the caption is also shifted. I want them to look like as they are now (centered) but caption should be aligned in one line. I also tried using `\begin{subfigure}[b]{.2\textwidth}` instead of `\begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}`  but this not keep the figures centeterd. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \begin{subfigure}{.2\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ExpoDomain}
      \caption{fig:a}
   \end{subfigure}
   \hfill
   \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ExpoDomain}
      \caption{fig:b}
   \end{subfigure}
   \hfill
   \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ExpoDomain}
      \caption{fig:c}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{fig:1 by 3 figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the total width of the line you have to pay attention for trailing spaces, eg. after `\end{subfigure}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \minipage{.2\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}\endminipage%
  \minipage{.3\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}\endminipage%
  \minipage{.5\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}\endminipage

 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.2\textwidth} \caption{fig:a} \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth} \caption{fig:b} \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth} \caption{fig:c} \end{subfigure}

 \caption{fig:1 by 3 figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the problem, adding [b] does not give what I exactly want. Tigers in suggestion are aligned at the bottom. I want them to be aligned in the center while keeping the caption aligned in a line.

Comment: see my edited answer